# Как увидеть список функций модуля PHP в VS CODE?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

Пересел на программу VS Code. Не понимаю, как увидеть список функций модуля PHP (на картинке вверху). Для JS список есть (на картинке внизу).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Установи, PHP Debug,PHP Intelliphense, отчасти они тебе помогут.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло  Intelliphense!